# Sparse recovery by convex optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, statistics, signal-processing, sparsity

This is problem 10.3.6a in Vershynin's *High Dimensional Probability* book that I'm self-studying. I wasn't sure how to do this problem. I tried finding a bound on the set the solution comes from and using theorem 10.3.4 in the book, but I wasn't able to do it.

> Assume $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix with independent, isotropic, and subgaussian rows $A_i$. Suppose $y$ is a know measurement and $Ax=y$. Show that an unknown $s$-sparse signal $x$ (i.e. at most $s$ nonzero entries) can be approximately recovered by solving the convex optimization problem
>
> $$\text{minimize } \|x'\|_1 \text{ s.t. } y=Ax'$$
>
> The recovery error satisfies
>
> $$\mathbb{E} \|\hat{x}-x\|_2 \leq C\sqrt{\frac{s\log n}{m}} \|x\|_2 $$
>
> where $\hat{x}=\text{argmin}_{Ax'=y}||x'||_1$

Comment: Can you provide some definitions? What is $A$? Is $\hat{x} = x'$?

Comment: So $\hat{x}$ is the solution from the convex optimization problem. $x$ is the unknown $s$-sparse signal that's being recovered.

Comment: A is a full rank matrix where $m<<n$.

Comment: Okay. Try *really hard* to pretend that you do not know anything about this problem other than what you see in this question (other than the general mathematical theory behind it). Can you see why it is that no one without access to your book or the patience to hunt through it to find this problem in it will be able to offer you any help at all? In particular, how is $A$ related to the signal? If you just pull a matrix out of your posterior, it isn't going allow you to prove anything.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That was part of the issue I was having solving the problem. I wasn't really sure what the assumptions on $A$ were since the above was all that was really given in the problem. I thought someone who has used the book might have been able to clarify that for me. Maybe the assumptions are the same as in theorem 10.2.1. I'll update the question above with an edit with more assumptions.

Comment: Much better. I suggest you also add the statement of theorem 10.3.4 to your post. That will significantly increase the number of people able to offer you help. Also, you should point out in the post that $\hat x$ is the solution ot the minimization problem instead of leaving that only clarified in the comments (one way of stating this is : $\hat x = \operatorname{arg\,min}_{Ax' = y} \|x'\|_1$).

Comment: Alright will do. I'll add the contents of the theorem in the evening when I get back.